# How to set dynamic row hight relative to the screen size

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to make a custom cell that's size should be screensize - 64; At a time my `UITableView` should display only the first cell and it should fill the whole screen. So I did like this.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath
{
   CGFloat rowSize=dm.screenHight-64.0;

   return rowSize;
}
```

But im getting an exception like this.

```
 *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _classicHeightForRowAtIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3347.44/UITableView.m:11127
```

2015-08-10 16:22:45.113 DEWN[8083:198498] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid row height provided by table delegate. Value must be greater than zero or UITableViewAutomaticDimension.'

Why is that. And how can I achive that.
Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: share complete code.. what is dm.screenHight

Comment: I am sorry. It was my mistake. I havent initialize the dm.screenHight. Thats why that error came.